# How would I add, multiply, and subtract these Matrices with the following code using data structures?

Tags: c, matrix, data-structures

So, I'm in the process of doing this program and I was given this set of code and told to implement those following functions to it, however I'm not sure how to construct a data structure from another structure. Any idea's as to how I could go about this? I know how to make a struct in C however to construct one off of another one I'm not sure. All the code does at this point is reads a matrix file and writes it. This program is actually supposed to take 2 matrices files and apply the following functions to and print it out in the same form, so what I'm trying to do is write three functions in which I do the operations in and return a data structure in which the write_matrix takes and returns the answer. I've tried a few ideas such as using the read_matrix sruct to create a multiply_matrix struct function however, It didn't work out. Any ideas?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

struct matrix
{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **data;
};

FILE *
input_from_args(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1) {
        return stdin;
    } else {
        return fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
}


struct matrix
read_matrix(FILE *src)
{
    struct matrix m;
    int i, j;

    fscanf(src, "%d", &m.rows);

    fscanf(src, "%d", &m.cols);

    m.data = (int **)malloc(m.rows * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < m.cols; i++) {
        m.data[i] = (int *)malloc(m.cols * sizeof(int));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m.cols; j++) {
            fscanf(src, "%d", &m.data[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return m;
}


void
write_matrix(FILE *dest, struct matrix m)
{
    int i, j;

    fprintf(dest, "%d\n", m.rows);
    fprintf(dest, "%d\n", m.cols);

    for (i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m.cols; j++) {
            fprintf(dest, "%d\t", m.data[i][j]);
        }

        fprintf(dest, "\n");
    }
}

void
clear_matrix(struct matrix m)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        free(m.data[i]);
    }

    free(m.data);
}

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    FILE *src = input_from_args(argc, argv);
    FILE *dest = stdout;
    struct matrix m;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (src == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: unable to open %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }else{
            m = read_matrix(src);
            fclose(src);
            write_matrix(dest, m);
        }
        clear_matrix(m);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The first for loop in `read_matrix` should loop until `i == m.rows`. It probably works anyway because you're dealing with square matrices.

Comment: yea, either way since were comparing the number of loops until it reaches the end of m.rows-1 so, either way works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is to separate matrix allocation from setting values. Right now, memory allocation happens exclusively in the context of reading from a file, but this doesn't allow you to allocate a matrix based on calculations.

My solution would be to write a function that only performs matrix allocation. Re-write `read_matrix` to call it so the allocation code is all in one place in case you need to change something later. Then call the allocation function inside your matrix operation functions.

Possible allocation function:

```c
typedef struct matrix matrix;

void
create_matrix(matrix *m, int rows, int cols)
{
    int i;
    m->rows = rows;
    m->cols = cols;
    m->data = malloc(m->rows * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        m->data[i] = malloc(m->cols * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

Note that I pass in a *pointer* to a matrix struct so that operations on this structure actually affect the variable passed in, as opposed to working on a local copy. Here is  a re-written `read_matrix` function that uses it:

```c
matrix
read_matrix(FILE *src)
{
    matrix m;
    int i, j, *row;

    fscanf(src, "%d", &m.rows);
    fscanf(src, "%d", &m.cols);

    create_matrix(&m, m.rows, m.cols);

    for (i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        row = m.data[i];
        for (j = 0; j < m.cols; j++) {
            fscanf(src, "%d", &row[j]);
        }
    }

    return m;
}
```

Now you can allocate a result matrix inside a function:

matrix
    add_matrix(matrix m, matrix n)
    {
        int i, j;
        matrix result;

```
    create_matrix(&result, m.rows, m.cols);

    // Perform the operation

    return result;
}
```

Many C API's require the calling function to perform any necessary allocation and pass in a pointer to the result structure. Success or failure can be indicated by the return value.

int add_matrix(matrix *result, matrix m, matrix n)
    {
        if ( /* Error checking logic fails */ )
        {
            return -1;
        }

```
    // Perform operation

    return 0;
}
```

Then this could be used like so:

```
matrix result;
create_matrix(&result, result_rows, result_cols);
int error = add_matrix(&result, m, n);
if (error = -1)
{
    // Handle error
}

// Etc...
```

The benefit of the second version is that the user of your matrix library knows they are responsible for calling `clear_matrix` at the end.

Comment: so would the above read_matrix handle two files with separate matrices in them?

Comment: You will need to call it once for each matrix file. This assumes there's only one matrix per file (just like the original).

Comment: did you mean to put struct infront of matrix in the write matrix funciton?

Comment: Nope. I added the line `typedef struct matrix matrix;`. I hate writing struct a million times.

Comment: ok so that technically automatically creates the struct for you?

Comment: I've been working with this for a little while and in my main function I've implemented a for loop so that the read_matrix get's called for as many matrix files however I can't pass src[i] because it's a pointer. Any idea how i can pass the second index that src is pointing too in read_matrix? Is the m->rows supposed to mean m.rows?

Comment: Sure. The semantics are more like it makes the compiler recognize uses of `matrix` to mean `struct matrix`. I could have said `typedef struct matrix zebra`, and every time I said `zebra`, the compiler would interpret that as `struct matrix`.

Comment: if I do &src[i] I get a core dump. I'm gonna try something and I'll let you know

Comment: I'm sensing that there's a different question there. It sounds like you're referring to code not posted here, and it also sounds a bit outside the scope of this question. I could be wrong.

Comment: Is the m->rows supposed to mean m.rows?

Comment: No. I need to pass a pointer to the create function so that the matrix passed in will be updated and not a local copy.

Comment: So this maybe a dumb question then, but do I litteraly copy the m->rows? btw I edited the code with the for loop in it.

Comment: So by running the program without the operations i'm getting -14037548 1684333904 -4197736 -4197588 when I run it. my matrices are http://imgur.com/92KfJTe

Comment: could these be memory addresses?

Comment: I just looked at your main function. You only ever open the first source file.

Comment: the &src[i] is what's causing the weird return. If i just run it with src, then it returns the correct values. Any idea how to open both files with the pointer src?

Comment: So when I write add_matrix(matrix m, matrix n) Do I use the create_matrix function just like I did in read_matrix? By doing this does that create the matrix that write_matrix reads?

Comment: You can figure this out. I believe in you.